# How to Save List view items in in resources <strings> and Use them on reload of Form? in c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

i want a method how can i save Multiple strings from list view items and save them forever in app's own Resources.

when i restart app these items Should remain in list view items. Please Help

Comment: how about properties.settings

Comment: I'd use txt/xml files instead of settings, since it's not settings at all.

Comment: Can You Please Tell the Method of using XML for That

Comment: @HasnainSiddiqui the same way you used to save `txt` file. Like this `File.WriteAllText("listViewItems.xml", xml);`

Comment: You can create a resource file(say MyStrings.resx) and add your strings to that file. Then access it like `MyStrings.mystring` in your project.

Comment: If you are using Resharper extension then you can select your string and press Ctrl+R,O to move that string to resources.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example using Dictionary

```
public static void AddResourceContent(Dictionary<string,string> a)
{
    foreach(string key in a.Keys)
    {
        using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@".\StringResources.resx"))
        {
            resx.AddResource(key, a[key]);
        }
    }
}
```